# Why isn't UI scaled properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new in unity. I'm making a simple 2D endless runner game.
My UI is scaled bigger than my camera size. How do I fix this?

I have tried changing the reference  resolution.

I expect the reference show great but the output is some weird looking text.

Comment: Could you include some screenshots for us to better understand your problem?

Comment: make your canvas scaler to scale with screen size, with 0.5 value (thats how I do it)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see it in the same zone as your center world position, you only need to change your `Canvas` component to be Camera space and then assign the camera with the `MainCamera` and that is it.

That is the easy way, a little harder way is changing it to `WorldSpace` but needs more adjustments.